# Is maintaining a socket connection to a server-side service bad for sending notifications to desktop applications?

Tags: java, c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm currently working on a semi-small spare time project to learn some new technologies. My plan is to create a chat application, client-side being built in WPF, and server-side with Java.

What I'm curious about is what approach I should take to sending and receiving messages. My current idea is to log the user in using a socket connection, and then maintain that connection to send that user notifications when he/she receives a message. Many people might have an application such as this run for many hours on their computer, so is maintaining a socket connection bad? If so, is there another approach I should consider instead?

Comment: Not sure if SO is the right place for this particular question. Answers here could be easily 
qualified as opinion based. Besides that I find it interesting. My initial thoughs on it are -> polling is also an option, condsider Push Notifications too.

Comment: Sockets do not have a login so you would need to a login process.  You may want to just send to standard input/output or a named pipe.

Comment: @dbl I didn't know where else to post this, but almost all programming question have multiple answers, driven by some opinion of what's best. But thank you for your answer, I'll look into both options :)

Comment: @Neebz eventually [software engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP socket connections can be left open for a long time, but will break eventually, for example when the network interfaces on either side of the connection are reconfigured, or when the server or client side software is restarted.

To detect breakage, some protocols include a ["heartbeat" mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing)). The client and server regularly exchange a message that says *"I'm still here, are you there?"* If  the client doesn't receive a heartbeat from the server for a while, it can assume that the connection has been broken and try to reconnect.

Comment: Ah yeah, I know that from some software that I use, and have actually implemented it before myself as well. But, would that mean that retaining a socket connection isn't a bad thing, as long as I check for the state of the connection once in a while?

Comment: No it's not a bad thing, lots of applications depend on connections remaining open relativity long periods of time. Remote computer access (SSH, RDP) is the first that comes to mind